# doing msbuild from the command line: getting errors for the referenced namespace 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools'

Tags: msbuild

i'm compiling a .net 3.5 solution with msbuild with this line of code:

```
msbuild.exe n:\temp\Thisnight.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /v:diag
```

and it gives me this error:

```
 error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'UnitTesting' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

i've gotten the latest source which (off course) builds in VS2010 itself.

Can't seem to figure out what i'm missing here....

EDIT

Seeing higher up in the command window this message:

```
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets : warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference.
 Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutra
l, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
```

I don't think i have to include this DLL by my project (because it's a MS dll?)

EDIT
What i've seen now: all projects are for the .Net 3.5 framework, but the testproject (which is the one giving me problems) is for the .Net 4.0 framework.
And the weird thing is: i can't change it.

It's a vs2010 solution with web. webservice,winforms,dll,setup and testprojects

Comment: Can you detail the contents of your solution? Kinda difficult to try and repro this with the current info.

Comment: It's a vs2010 solution with 16 projects (web, webservice, winforms and dll).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the Microsoft.Common.Targets file you will see :

```
<!--
    The SearchPaths property is set to find assemblies in the following order:

        (1) Files from current project - indicated by {CandidateAssemblyFiles}
        (2) $(ReferencePath) - the reference path property, which comes from the .USER file.
        (3) The hintpath from the referenced item itself, indicated by {HintPathFromItem}.
        (4) The directory of MSBuild's "target" runtime from GetFrameworkPath.
            The "target" runtime folder is the folder of the runtime that MSBuild is a part of.
        (5) Registered assembly folders, indicated by {Registry:*,*,*}
        (6) Legacy registered assembly folders, indicated by {AssemblyFolders}
        (7) Resolve to the GAC.
        (8) Treat the reference's Include as if it were a real file name.
        (9) Look in the application's output folder (like bin\debug)
    -->
```

VS runs MSBuild in its own environment, I don't know the differences either but did you try adding the lacking assembly path in command line by modifying the AssemblyFolders items. You have a tuto here : http://www.beefycode.com/post/Resolving-Binary-References-in-MSBuild.aspx .

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not sure if you can override AssemblySearchPaths in command line. Did you try adding a custom target like it's shown in the tuto? Or else you could directly modify Microsoft.Common.Targets but I don't think it's a good solution...

Comment: Didn't get it to work, hope someone someday will read this post and give me a solution. Didn't think upfront it would be so difficult. Have been working on it for > 6 hours, and it was not important enough to continue. Did mark this one as answer for the effort BB took.

Comment: I forgot this question. I am currently facing the same problem and I think you simply cannot run VS Unit Test outside VS (i.e. with MsBuild). The lacking dll is in the VS10\Common7\IDE dir and even if I referenced it well, I could not manage to get it work outside of VS. Maybe it used MsTest or needs some VS stuff to work. I mark the question as favorite to see if anyone has a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

did you run vcvars32.bat in your cmd shell?

Comment: and can i also schedule it from my cruisecontrol (because when i get the msbuild running, i want to run it from my cruisecontrol), or am i to greedy now :)

Comment: It's part of the vs distribution, under the Common7\Tools folder.

Comment: i've run the batch file in my command prompt and the ran the msbuild task , but it didn't work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: by the way: it's on a dev machine, so i have VS2010 installed.

Comment: hmm. not sure. Try to open the solution in VS on that machine and see if the IDE recognizes the references in the reference tab. How did you reference this DLL? You could try deleting the reference and re-adding it to the project again. VS runs msbuild to build the project, so it must be a subtle difference in the environment in which the process starts. Also - are you sure it is the same type of VS2010 install? The test environment is not available in the base version, only on some versions (like Professional and Test)

Comment: It's ON my dev machine, so the machine i'm running msbuild on is the same machine i developed the solution on. And the dll's were reference by the project once i created it by a simple file, new project, test project. But i'll try to delete and re-add them, maybe that helps.

Comment: it seems that it is missing for this assembly     c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll

Comment: i tried adding it to the msbuild with /p:AddModules and /p:AssemblySearchPaths, but unfortunately, didn't work

Comment: and i can't figure out where to look for the MSbuild command(s) VS executes when it compiles my solution

Answer (score 1):

try running:

msbuild /version

Make sure it's the 3.5 version and not something older.

Make sure the MS dll is here, or somewhere like that:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll